Why Microsoft don't publish the list of tags on DockerHub repository
Does anyone knows why Microsoft don't use the "normal" repository style on DockerHub ? Why we can't browse the versions and tags ?

All the other official images (and unofficial) can be searched and explored on DockerHub :

This is very disturbing as It's difficult to enumerate the current versions.

Because the images aren't actually hosted on dockerhub but rather on mcr.microsoft.com, and there you can also see the tags. https://mcr.microsoft.com/product/dotnet/aspnet/tags Their entries on dockerhub are mostly there to point people over to their own registry.

Thank you for the answer. you are right, but how can you check that a current version is not supported ? The About tab don't list current supported tags. There's a small "Supported Tags Only" checkbox on the search. Are you using this to check if a tag is still supported ? Any github release note or blog information source to subscribe ?
